# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append') unsure why?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am using Angular TypeScript with d3.js. I created a bar chart but it is not being displayed and unsure why. I made private classes and implemented them into the `ngOnInit()` class but when I live server it, there is nothing and it is blank. On the terminal it showing no problems but I'm not sure why it's not being displayed. I'm not sure if I have to call it into the bar-char.component.html. I created a small dataset just to see if the bar chart will be visualized.  Fairly new to Angular/TypeScript and d3.js. Here is my code:

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit 
 {
  private svg:any;
  private dataSet = [10,20,30,32,47,50,76];


  private margin = 50; 
  private height = 100 - (this.margin * 2); 
  private width = 200 - (this.margin * 2); 

  public createSvg(): void{
   var svg = d3.select('barchart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("width", this.height + (this.margin * 2) 
 )
  .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 
   2))
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin 
   + "," + this.margin + ')');

  d3.select('barchart');
  }

 //x axis band scale

 private drawBars(dataSet: any[]): void{

   const xAxis = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, this.width])
  .domain(dataSet.map(d => d.Framework))
  .padding(0.2);

// drawing the x-axis 
  this.svg.append('g')
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 
    this.height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis))
   .selectAll("text")
   .attr("tranform" 
   ,"translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
   .style("text-anchor", "end");

   const yAxis= d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, 100])
   .range([this.height, 0]);

   this.svg.append("g")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis));

   //creation of bar graph and fill in the bars


   this.svg.selectAll("bars")
   .data(dataSet)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   //.attr("x", d => xAxis(d.Framework))
   //.attr("y", d => yAxis(d.Stars))
   .attr("width", xAxis.bandwidth())
   //.attr("height", (d) => this.height - 
    yAxis(d.Stars))
   .attr("fill", "#d04a35");
}

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.createSvg();
 this.drawBars(this.dataSet);

}
```

After I run the server I get an error on the console about it not reading the append properties. Here is a picture of the error messages: [ERROR TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'append')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVAYE.png)

What are some good tips for the future to not repeat the same mistake? I am very new to using these technologies.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As the answer states: var svg = d3.select should be this.svg =

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same question again. I already explained the issue in a comment under your first question.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with debugging to find out which append its erroring on, but something I sometimes do to deal with issues like this is add [optional chaining.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

It looks like you may actually need to reference the global svg in createSvg()

```
public createSvg(): void{
   this.svg = d3.select('barchart')
  ?.append('svg')
  .attr("width", this.height + (this.margin * 2) 
 )
  .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 
   2))
  ?.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin 
   + "," + this.margin + ')');

  d3.select('barchart');
  }
```